# TypeScript: Subfunction in DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working on creating DefinitelyTyped for the private package (I cannot change source code) and I cannot find any way to implement type like this:

```
  GlobalNameSpace.foo = function(arg) {} 
  GlobalNameSpace.foo.bar1 = function(arg) {} ;
  GlobalNameSpace.foo.foo2 = function(arg) {};
```

I've tried using `class` in my `index.d.ts` but `foo` is is not a `class` sadly is a normal function.

my attempt:

```
declare namespace GlobalNameSpace {
    function foo(options: any): void;
}
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: @Caramiriel thank you! It looks like this solve my problem for now :D

Comment: Alright, I've converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function, such as:

```
function foo(options: any): void;
```

can be expressed as a callable object, like so:

```
const foo: {
    (options: any): void;
}
```

Also, any object can have additional properties. These properties can be callable as well, so the following is perfectly valid:

```
declare namespace GlobalNameSpace {
    const foo: {
        (options: any): void;

        bar1: { (arg: any): void };
        foo2: { (arg: any): void };
    }
}
```

Note that a `const` variable is slightly different from a `function`. Functions are hoisted for example. But in the case above they're equivalent.